# ListViewItem add progressbar to selected item on click

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have created a `listview`, with custom adapter.
When I click an item within the list view, I download data async.

My question is, how can I add a progress bar (indeterminate) to the selected ListViewItem.  Note that they will be able to click multiple ListViewItems (obviously not the same one while its downloading), which means there could by x number of progress bars at any given time.

I have tried adding it  by casting the view (2nd param) to a view group and using AddView, but to no avail.  It seems the view is the ListView and not the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listview item xml should also have a progressbar with visibility set to gone. When you're about to start download (on onPreExecute() of your async task) set progressbar to visible. When done downloading, set it to gone again.

Comment: I was thinking about this.  But lets say I have 200 items in my listview, won't this effect performance, if they all had progress bars (even if not visible)?

Comment: So should I be handling the click event in the getView() method? or override my listfragment onitemclick?

Comment: Android will recycle the view so all of the listview items won't be rendered at the same time, provided that you implemented your adapter's getView() accordingly (Using ViewHolder and not inflating the view each time getView() called).

Comment: handling in getView() is fine.

Comment: Use ViewHolder pattern while inflating adapter to the listview so that your listview's item view can be resued.